# Java Timer unknown event

Tags: java, swing, events, timer, freeze

When I execute the following method in my program some components change when the timer runs out. For example a jTextArea I created changes in size without any events containing a construction to change its size. It doesn't matter if I first expand the jTextArea and then start the timer or vice versa.

```
//Show Debug Information for given Seconds with given Text
void giveUserInformation(String input, boolean function, int duration) {
    //Debug information and label visibility handling
    jLabelDebug.setVisible(true);
    jLabelDebug.setText(input);

    //Image
    if (function)
        jLabelDebug.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/ok-icon.png")));
    else
        jLabelDebug.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/Actions-edit-delete-icon.png")));

    //Show duration
    if (timerShowDurationRuns) {
        timerShowDuration.cancel();
        timerShowDuration = new Timer();
    }

    timerShowDurationRuns = true;
    //fadeIn();
    timerShowDuration.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jLabelDebug.setVisible(false);
            timerShowDurationRuns = false;
            //fadeOut();
        }
    }, duration * 1000);
    setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}
```

Comment: you are setting the label to invisible - thats instruction to change things - plus where is the jtextArea?

Comment: Assuming you're using a layout manager, when you change a component's visible state, the layout will need to be calculated to compensate for the lose of that component (as a invisible component occupies no space)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the JTextArea you should use code like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

Now the text area will be able to determine its preferred size and will remain fixed as you add text to it.

Then when you add it to the GUI you use code like:

```
frame.add( new JScrollPane( textArea ) );
```

Now as you add more data the text area size will remain fixed, but scroll bars will appear when required.